# disable browser back button using PHP

Tags: php, firefox, browser

can any body tell "How to disable browser back button" using PHP.
I can able to disable using javascript but there is a way to disable using PHP.

I need only for dynamic pages not static pages.

Comment: Maybe accept a few more answers to your questions? That's 22 rep to you if you do ;-)

Comment: There's no way to do this via PHP.  It's generally poor practice to try to disable native browser functionality.  You might consider a different approach.  What are you trying to accomplish by disabling the back button?

Comment: hi, thank u for u r reply. My intention is, if user is in authenticated page(already logged in),and trying to click the back button, it will go to the previous page. This will not happened right..

Answer (score 3):

That's client related problem, so no there is no way to disable the back button using server side.

Plus I think it's a bad practice to disable it.

If you want to avoid re submission of forms when the user click the back button, your should take a look in the [redirect after post pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to disable it via PHP - PHP is a server side language, meaning it cannot interact with anything outside it's server directly.

You could always get PHP to print some JavaScript to disabled the back button.

James

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable Back button with PHP. You can disable caching using something like this:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

This will add the appropriate headers to the HTTP request to inform the browser it should reload the page instead of fetching it through a cache.

Comment: No - for a GET operation, under some circumstances, many browsers will ignore instructions not to use a cached copy when either the back button is pressed or via the javascript history object. I'm not aware of any which do this after a POST.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server sided language. Non of your php code ever is executed on your clients machine.
PHP just "generates" the pag and sends the reult to the client.
The only sullotion i can think of is, making your PHP code include the javascript in the page you create.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your intention, instead of disabling the back button (not a very good idea usabilitywise anyway) you could do a checking with PHP like this (pseudocode) on the login page:

```
if user is logged in then
     redirect to last page
end
```

So, if the user clicks the back button, she will be redirected back to the page she was. This pseudocode is of course a bit oversimplistic, you should probably do some checkings, and you should probably warn the user of the redirection, but that's the idea.

Comment: hi, thanks u r reply. I did the following way: First user signed up,  set the session value and when he clicks the back button, i put the condition inside the main layout. And here i included the java script: function noBack()
   {      
    window.history.forward(1);
    setTimeout("noBack()", 500);
   }  
    $jquery(document).ready(function() {  
     noBack();        
     window.onpageshow=function(evt){if(evt.persisted)noBack();}
     window.onunload=function(){void(0);}
    });